# Indicate in Windows which video files have been viewed

Tags: windows, video, vlc-media-player

A rather specific problem...

I watch video's using VLC.  (I've found Windows Media Player and XBMC too cumbersome.)  We are always trying to find which was the latest show in a series that we last watched.

Would be awesome to have this tracked somehow, i.e. an indicator in Windows Explorer showing what has been watched/partially watched etc.

Cheers.

Comment: Me To, I only want to watch something once then have it tagged. Problem is when would a program even tag it?  When it is loaded first, or after it hits the end only, computers assuming humans :-)  just doesnt work out well.  What I do here is watch a "directory" of file items by clicking the file item (as opposed to opening in program) When I am done with it I put it in a Folder called Watched.  Because I am right there at the files as opposed to a playlist or other methods, its easy drag and drop.  Speaking of playlists :-) You could always use those, same problems.

Comment: Perhaps VLC's Bookmarks feature might be useful?

Comment: Me too. As well as wanting to know where I'm up to in several different *series*, I've got a couple of thousand *movies* that I'd like to view in "most recently watched" sequence. Partly because I just forget things, but partly because it's sometimes good to just focus on that part of the list containing movies that I liked, but haven't watched for years. Foobar2000 handles this very well for music tracks by maintaining a "date/time last played" field that's only updated when played for more than X seconds, or X% of total track duration. Can someone identify or write a VLC plugin, maybe?